# MySQL - Join a table twice with a main table

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I'm not sure if this can be done. But I just wanted to check with the experts out here.

My case is: 
I have a table tbl_campaign which basically stores a campaigns which has a one to many relation with a table called tbl_campaign_user where the users that were selected during the campaign are stored along with the campaign id (tbl_campagin_user.cu_campaign_id = tbl_campaign.campaign_id ).

The second table (tbl_campaign_user) has a status field which is either 0 / 1 denoting unsent/sent. I wanted to write a single sql query which would read the campaign data as well as the number of sent and unsent campaign users (which is why I'm joining twice on the second table). 
I tried this below, but I get the same number of count as sent and unsent.

```
SELECT `tbl_campaign`.*, 
COUNT(sent.cu_id) as numsent, 
COUNT(unsent.cu_id) as num_unsent   FROM (`tbl_campaign`) 

LEFT JOIN tbl_campaign_user as sent on  (sent.cu_campaign_id = tbl_campaign.campaign_id and sent.cu_status='1')

LEFT JOIN tbl_campaign_user as unsent on  (unsent.cu_campaign_id = tbl_campaign.campaign_id and unsent.cu_status='0')


WHERE `tbl_campaign`.`campaign_id` = '19'
```

---

I tried debugging by breaking the query into two parts:
=>

```
SELECT `tbl_campaign`.*, 

COUNT(unsent.cu_id) as num_unsent   FROM (`tbl_campaign`) 

Left join tbl_campaign_user as unsent on  (unsent.cu_campaign_id = tbl_campaign.campaign_id and unsent.cu_status='0')

WHERE `tbl_campaign`.`campaign_id` = '19'
```

---

The above works exactly as wanted. And so does the one below:

=>

```
SELECT `tbl_campaign`.*, 
COUNT(sent.cu_id) as numsent   FROM (`tbl_campaign`) 

Left join tbl_campaign_user as sent on  (sent.cu_campaign_id = tbl_campaign.campaign_id and sent.cu_status='1')

WHERE `tbl_campaign`.`campaign_id` = '19'
```

---

I am not sure what I've been doing wrong while merging the two. I know I don't know much about joins so possibly a conceptual error? Please could anyone help me?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to join tbl_campaign_user once and 
count (sum, whatever) how many times cu_status was zero/one.

```
SELECT `tbl_campaign`.id, 
count(u.id) as num_all_campaign_users
sum(u.cu_status) as num_sentcampaign_users, 
count(u.id) - sum(u.cu_status) as num_unsent_campaign_users   
FROM `tbl_campaign` c 
LEFT JOIN tbl_campaign_user as u on (u.cu_campaign_id = c.campaign_id)
WHERE `tbl_campaign`.`campaign_id` = '19'  
group by `tbl_campaign`.id
```

Note that this is sort of pseudo code, you may have to elaborate 
the sum/count in the select clause and the group by clause as well.

Comment: Hi bpgergo, thanks for your quick reply. 

I changed the group by to tbl_campaign.campaign_id and corrected the ON condition to user.cu_campaign_id instead of unsent.cu... (I know that was a typo from you, but just in case someone would want to use on a similar occassion).

However, what I am seeking for is a relative insight on joins - what if my table did not have a cu_status so that no SUM was possible?  I'd like more help on that :)

Comment: Append:: Would LEFT JOINing two subqueries be the only option in that case?

Comment: If your tbl_campaign_user.cu_status field did not have possible values of zero and one but character flags, then your sum would be something like this: `sum(if(cu_status='S', 1, 0))` See mysql [if](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if). In such a case, SUM is your friend: you have to find a function which gives 1 for the desired cases and zero for all others and then use SUM to count the desired cases. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I've however edited the typos in the query you wrote to: 
-------------------
SELECT c.campaign_id, count( u.cu_id ) AS num_all_campaign_users, sum( u.cu_status ) AS num_sentcampaign_users, count( u.cu_id ) - sum( u.cu_status ) AS num_unsent_campaign_users
FROM `tbl_campaign` c
LEFT JOIN tbl_campaign_user AS u ON ( u.cu_campaign_id = c.campaign_id )
WHERE c.`campaign_id` = '19'
GROUP BY c.campaign_id